# jQuery replaceWith not working without DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, replacewith

I am trying to do some element manipulation on a Node.js server where I need to take a string of HTML, then replace some of the nodes with other node types. This was working fine when I was doing it with a DOM but as soon as I don't have a DOM it does not work.

In a very simple example, I want to do something like this... where I find all the `div` elements and replace with `spans`.

```
const html = '<html><div>hello</div><div>hello</div></html>';
const obj = $(html);
const filter = $(obj).find('div');

for (let j = filter.length; j >= 0; j--) {
  $(filter[j]).replaceWith("<span>goodbye</span>");
}

console.log(obj);
```

I can't just do a find and replace on the string as I don't want all elements I am doing a filter based on various things before I do this.

It is not working saying that the node is not an element. Is there a way I can do this? I have also tried using JSDOM to do this but again, no luck.

I want the console here to show the HTML element with two `spans` rather than two `divs`, I have tried adding a jsfiddle for this however I am getting a different error on here too, if anyone can help it would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/vkn285a1/1/

** **UPDATE** **

From the answer below, I have updated but I am now getting my desired result, thank you.. I had to change to use SVG which is what I am actually parsing and it worked a treat

```
  const html = "<svg><g><text>hello</text><text>hello</text></g></svg>";
  const obj = $.parseHTML(html);

  const filter = $(obj).find("text");

  for (let j = filter.length; j >= 0; j--) {
    $(filter[j]).replaceWith("<span>goodbye</span>");
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is following:

```
const obj = $(html);
```

this *obj* is NULL.

You have to use parseHTML function to get object from string as following.

```
const html = '<html><div>hello</div><div>hello</div></html>';
const obj = $.parseHTML(html);
```

Then *obj* will be an array of divs in html tag of string.

[image]

After that, you can try anything for those objects that are not NULL.

Comment: legend thank you so much, this has worked in Node.JS